# Is it okay to ask `what does this mean` questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Suppose that I come across a piece of code, a function for example, that has a name that makes absolutely no sense to me. I try to google it and I find a bunch of other code snippets/functions that have the same name in a (somewhat) similar context. 
However I still do not manage to figure out the meaning of this name is it okay for me to ask about what that name means on SO?

Comment: asking what that name means or asking what that function does? That's a big difference, the first one shouldn't be asked on SO and the second can be asked on SO, I think.

Comment: @Wouter the first alternative is the one I'm referring to, however what if it is some kind of convention that I'm unaware of, wouldn't it be prudent of me to ask?

Comment: Of course its OK to ask. Do you have a link to the original question?

Comment: @Johan here ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155218/what-does-ips-mean-in-ismainips#comment21340251_15155218

Answer (score 3):

No, not really. Is is a too localized and maybe unanswerable question. How are we supposed to know what that stands for? It could have many different meanings based on further context (is it used elsewhere in the software? Is it maybe documented?) which only unfolds when we see the whole application.

Comment: Of course I agree if it is only localized to my codebase, but in this case I assume that the questioner has seen the exact same (or similar enough) naming to know that it is not only his/hers codebase that have this name. As I mentioned in the comments, what if it some kind of convention that I'm unaware of?